# Datastore Emulator Query/Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I  have  installed  google  datastore  emulator  in  my  local machine  along  with  it  written a  sample  spring  boot application  which  performs  crud  operations  on  datastore.
When  i  hit  the  rest  endpoints  through postman  i  can  actually  see  the  data  gets  inserted in  datastore  in  gcp  console

can  someone  help  me  by  clearing  below  queries:

**1>Even  though  using  an  emulator  in  local ,  whether  data  gets  inserted  to  actual datastore  in  cloud (gcp)**

**2>what  is  the  purpose  of  emulator** (if  qn  1  is  correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No data is inserted on Datastore servers, everything is local as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#emulator_data_directories)

> The emulator simulates Datastore by creating /WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin in a specified data directory and storing data in local_db.bin. By default, the emulator uses the data directory ~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/. The local_db.bin file persists between sessions of the emulator. You can set up multiple data directories and think of each as a separate, local Datastore mode instance. To clear the contents of a local_db.bin file, stop the emulator and manually delete the file.

2. There are multiple uses for example:

- To develop and test your application locally without writing actual Data to the servers hence avoiding charges during the development process
- Help you generate indexes for your production Firestore in Datastore mode instance and delete unneeded indexes, that could be [exported](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import#export_entities_in_the_emulator) then into production

*Edit*

In order to use the emulator on the same machine it's recommended to set the environment variables automatically as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#automatically_setting_the_variables)

Comment: local_db.bin is  never  created  when  i  checked   the   /WEB-INF/appengine-generated/         i  have  added spring.cloud.gcp.emulator-enabled=true,spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator-host=localhost:8484 in  application  properties,can  u  help  me  resolve  in  why   call  is  not  redirected  to  my  emulator  instead  of  inserting  into  datastore  server

Comment: By your comment I assume that your application and emulator are running on the same machine. If so avoid setting the application properties manually and use the [automatic setting variables](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#automatically_setting_the_variables)

Comment: got  it ,   now  the  issue  is  fixed  thanks  for  the  info

Comment: Excellent, if the answer helped you to fix the issue I invite you to mark it as accepted so it gets more visibility to the community